# reversing modulo equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have this equation:

```
y = a^N mod M
```

`N` and `M` are constant.

I want to reverse the equation and calculate `a` using `y`.

something like this:
`a = ???`

how can I do this?

assume I have `N`, `M` and `y`. Now I want to calculate `a`.

thanks

Comment: Please use [$\rm \LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler question of the existence of $a$, given $y$, $N=2$, $M=p$ (a prime) has an answer by the *law of quadratic reciprocity* and calculations via the *Legendre symbol*. It can be extended to the case when $M$ is square free (product of distinct primes), using the *Chinese remainder theorem*, since $y$ is a square modulo $p_1p_2\dotsm p_r$ if and only if it is a square modulo each of $p_1, p_2,\dots, p_r$.

Once you have a solution modulo $p_i$, you can recursively obtain a solution modulo $p_i^k$ for any $k$ via *Hensel's lifting*.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the existence and uniqueness of $a$ satisfying the equation above given $y$, $N$, and $M$ is not, in general, guaranteed - there may be infinitely many such $a$, or none.

For example, take $y=0$, $N=1$, $M=2$. Your question in this particular case becomes: "I know that $a$ is even (i.e. $a^1 \equiv 0 \mod 2$); how can I compute $a$?"